# ErrorException : Use of undefined constant user_id - assumed 'user_id'

Tags: laravel

> ErrorException  : Use of undefined constant user_id - assumed
>   'user_id'

(this will throw an **Error** in a future version of `PHP`)

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

    class StocksTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            DB::table('accounts')->insert([
                'user_id' => user_id,
                'product_name' => str_random(100),
                'product_code'  => str_random(10),
                'details'  => str_random(100),
                'price'  => str_random(10),
                'cost' => str_random(10),
              'quntity'  => str_random(10),
            ]);

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: do You have a variable or constant  called user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is with this line `'user_id' => user_id,`,
seems like you inserting random data. so you also need to insert user_id(perhaps random)

so now user_id is not a constant because you did not define it up right.
so it should be some variable like `$user_id`, You can use `mt_rand($min, $max)`.
for random integer. 
But be user you need a random user_id. Otherwise if you already have `user_id`, then store it in variable like `$user_id = Auth::id()` if need logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

In your insert function, `'user_id' => user_id,` this line is causing the problem. I think you want to insert an id like 1/2/3.. So either use constant like 1/2/3 or a variable `$user_id` which you have to define before with a value. And if you want to insert a string use like `"user_id"`. Look for `""`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `user_id` by below code:

```
\App\User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id
```